# How to use chart control in asp.net Framework 2.0?

Tags: c#, asp.net, graph

I working in a project done in .net Framework 2.0, I need chart control for displaying chart in web application i can't use chart control its hidden in tools.

I also referenced "system.web.datavisualization.dll" , even its not working.

can anyone suggest any solution for this.

Thanks
R.Karthik

Answer (score 0):

Please refer this [Link](http://www.nilzorblog.com/2010/01/using-microsoft-chart-controls-in-net.html) to develop chart control in .NET framework2.0 . There are third party controls for developing charts here is the [Third party Controls Link](http://www.highcharts.com/). It's costless free to download and implement.

Comment: Hi @Shankar, it's showing USD.590 for commercial purpose...Its any other there for free.

Answer (score 0):

There is a Turkish oldsaying: They asked the wolf: "Why is your neck is thick?", he replied: "I do it myself." :)

So I checked some solutions but they all have some other problems, and I decided to do it myself.

Here is a very simple function. (You can convert it to C#)

```
....

    Dim gecbmp As Bitmap = grafikyap(toplamsureler, aylar)
    gecbmp.Save("C:\inetpub\wwwroot\musteri\gecbmp.jpg", Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg)
    Image1.ImageUrl = "./gecbmp.jpg"

....

Private Function grafikyap(ByVal toplamsureler() As Integer, ByVal aylar() As String) As Bitmap
    Dim arkarenkR As Integer = 255
    Dim arkarenkG As Integer = 255
    Dim arkarenkB As Integer = 255

    grafikyap = Nothing
    objBitmap = New Bitmap(390, 320, System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format16bppRgb555)
    objGraphics = Graphics.FromImage(objBitmap)
    objGraphics.Clear(Color.FromArgb(arkarenkR, arkarenkG, arkarenkB)) 'for the background color

    Dim artim As Integer
    artim = 30 'width of the bar
    Dim strxyeri As Integer
    Dim stryyeri As Integer
    Dim myfont2 As New System.Drawing.Font("Courier New", 12, FontStyle.Regular, GraphicsUnit.Pixel)

    Dim yuk As Integer ' height of the bar
    Dim bolen As Integer = 2 ' to fit the bars inside the image
    For qq = 1 To 6
        yuk = toplamsureler(qq) / bolen
        strxyeri = 330 - ((qq - 1) * 2 * artim)
        stryyeri = 300 - yuk
        objGraphics.FillRectangle(Brushes.Blue, strxyeri, stryyeri, artim, yuk)
        objGraphics.DrawString(Trim(Str(toplamsureler(qq))), myfont2, Brushes.Black, strxyeri, stryyeri - 20)
        objGraphics.DrawString(Trim(aylar(qq)), myfont2, Brushes.Black, strxyeri, 300)
    Next qq
    grafikyap = objBitmap
    objGraphics.Dispose()
End Function
```